# Why is my shell script hanging on `apt-get -y upgrade`?

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, scripting, apt, remote-management

Ubuntu :

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y update
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y upgrade
sudo reboot
```

Script is always interrupted after upgrade and then it will stay on the command line, it will never reboots. How to run non-interactive shell scripts correctly, is there a way ?

Comment: We can't help you with so little information. Post a transcript of the upgrade session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
apt-get -qy update > /dev/null
apt-get -qy dist-upgrade >> /var/log/apt/scripted-upgrades.log
```

You can send them both to /dev/null if you want-- but once its gone you can never look at what went wrong after issuing the command.

Also if your /etc/apt/sources.list is in bad shape, running a plain interactive

```
apt-get update
```

should clue you in.

The other guy has it right for scheduling updates for the system. This is for when I am calling a setup script once when I'm configuring a new server-- only you will know which one is appropriate for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I'd take a look at this topic on the Ubuntu Documentation site titled: [AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoWeeklyUpdateHowTo). It covers pretty much all aspects of how to keep you system up to date either manually, semi-manualy (downloads updates but doesn't install) to full automated (downloads & installs).

To do the unattended automated route you can enlist the help of the package [unattended-upgrade](http://csurs.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?unattended-upgrade%208). There is even an entire page dedicated to doing [Automatic Updates](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html), which gives you explicit details in setting up this feature.